# setting the openCV configuration in an openGL project produce several errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, opencv, windows-7-x64

I have a win32 solution which is set for openGL; it works well; but I want to write a function which use functions of openCV; I set the configuration for openCV for both X86 and X64;;I commented the openCV function and just to test the correctness of configuration, I run it;
but when I want to run it on X64 I faced with the error below:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'GWL_HINSTANCE' : undeclared identifier    D:\matrix\matrixProjection\src\ControllerMain.cpp   35  1   matrixProjection

Error   2   error C2664: 'CreateDialogParamW' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'DLGPROC'    D:\matrix\matrixProjection\src\DialogWindow.cpp 47  1   matrixProjection
```

Error 2 points to this line of code:

```
HWND DialogWindow::create()
{
   /*-->this line*/ handle = ::CreateDialogParam(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), parentHandle, Win::dialogProcedure, (LPARAM)controller);

    return handle;
}
```

but on Debug Win32 configure, it runs;

I used openGL32 in my project; is there any probability to be the cause? is there any X64 version for openGL?
I know that there is something needed in X64 mode which my solution  can not handle it;
I googled a lot about it but I did not find any solution; How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that that we can not use opengl32 with opencv64 simultaneously; so however I am working on x46 system but I set the opencv32 and it is working well;)